# ¿Cómo puedo validar que un cliente pueda comprar solo una suscripción de un solo tipo de periodo en Woocommerce?

Tags: woocommerce, wordpress-plugin

tengo una tienda en línea en Woocommerce y necesito hacer la siguiente validación para los clientes:

Manejo dos tipos de suscripciones en mi página: mensual y anual, por lo tanto lo que quiero es validar que un cliente solo pueda adquirir una suscripción de un solo tipo ,es decir, mensual o anual, pero de diferentes productos. Por ejemplo
Lo que quiero lograr:
Producto x =$500 mensual
Producto y =$400 mensual

Lo que no quiero (que no se permita seleccionar suscripciones de diferente periodicidad):
Producto x=$5500 anual
Producto y=$400 mensual

Este es el link de mi página : [oblako.com.mx](https://oblako.com.mx/paquetes-de-negocio/)

Conocen algún plugin o hook que pueda hacer esta validación? Utilizo el plugin de Woocommerce subscriptions para las suscripciones. Les agradecería también sugerencias para abordar este tema de otra forma.

Comment: como están creadas las diferentes suscripciones ? son variaciones o productos agrupados? https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/subscriptions/faq/#section-12

Comment: @aloMalbarez son productos simples pero con el plugin de suscripciones les agrego la opción de suscripción mensual y anual.